# Non-http links in SharePoint: not allowed?

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, mms

I've been searching through various types of sites that I can create using SharePoint 2010, and it seems that the only one I can't use (a simple list view in a web part) is the only one that will accept non "http" links.

A Document Library won't even let me create non-http links, so I went with a Wiki, thinking that surely this would let me enter whatever I want. But it's not so! It let me create mms:// links (about 50 of them, before I saved), but once I save+closed the page, SharePoint decided that it would do me a favor and remove all the addresses from the hyperlinks! Now I have 50 empty links that only open a new tab when clicked. Of course, I tested this with an http:// link to Google and, sure enough, that one worked after save.

My question is: is there **any** way for me to avoid Microsoft's walled garden approach here and use mms:// for some of my links using native options? Or will I have to alter the HTML directly?

There was [a similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70603/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-hyperlink-column-to-allow-for-non-http) on Sharepoint.SE nearly a year ago, but it got zero answers. Hopefully this one will garner more attention.

Comment: @RobertLindgren Are you kidding me? First of all, it's not an "exact duplicate", if you bother to read both questions, there are some important differences. Second of all, no one answered that question and they certainly wouldn't now. You shouldn't mark questions as duplicates if the "original" never got answers.

Comment: Sorry @TylerH I must admit I missed the part about you inputing the URL in a wiki-page content and not in a column. My marking as duplicate was based on my misinterpretation of both questions being about the rewriting of URL:s in URL type columns :) (by the way, the fact that a question has not gotten any answers is not reason for consider it a duplicate. The system of marking as duplicate is based on finding questions with the exact same problem or question)

Comment: @RobertLindgren too much hurry can cause problems :) give us chance to earn some flags and badges too man ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but I figured this out.  You have to first use an HTTP or HTTPs address as a placeholder.  I just use google, just to get the link to save.  Then go back in and edit the link, and it will accept other link types such as file://.  The kicker here is that if you then click on the item in the Name column, it pulls up a blank ASPX page. So you need to then enable the URL column in your view, and clicking that URL is what will actually take you to the file you've linked to.

I personally wasn't satisfied with this, so the alternative is to edit the blank ASPX page, and in the Head, change the Meta tag to
`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=pasteyourURLhere" />`
and this will cause the page to redirect to the file you're actually trying to link to.  You may also want to include the word Loading in the Body, so the user doesn't panic when it takes a few extra seconds for their document to load.  It's a little extra work, but this way you can reliably use just the Name column to get things to load whether it's a file or a link.

Comment: Unfortunately we have since migrated our 2010 SharePoint environment to SharePoint Online, so I'm unable to test/confirm whether this solution would have worked for me, but it sounds like the method I was already expecting to have to use (directly modify the HTML).